# npm test with Node.js server startup

Tags: node.js, npm

What is the best practice way when invoking tests with npm to start a Node.js server and then run the test command? I am trying the following in my `package.json`, but it is failing. Note, I need to invoke `node api.js` in the background and then I wish to exit it after the `jasmine-node` command finishes.

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node api.js & && jasmine-node test"
}
```

Comment: Have you considered booting the app within your tests?

Answer (score 1):

You can give a try with [Supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest), thus you simulate your server (setting up an agent) and shut it down when tests are done. This also avoids some tricky hacks to shut down the server process once tests are done.

**Edit:**
The advantage with supertest rather than frisby is that you don't have to call a full URI, you can setup an agent from your app object (example is from supertest readme):

```
var request = require('supertest');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/user', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ name: 'tobi' });
});

request(app)
  .get('/user')
  .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
  .expect('Content-Length', '15')
  .expect(200)
  .end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

Comment: I am already using http://frisbyjs.com/ (frisby) anyway to do it with that?

Comment: It seems that you have to call an explicit URI with Frisby. With supertest you can setup your own agent (see answer edit).

Answer (score 0):

Ended up writing a simple bash script `bin/test-runner.bash` to handle this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eo pipefail; [[ $TRACE ]] && set -x

node api.js & SERVER_PID=$!
sleep 1
jasmine-node test
kill "$SERVER_PID"
```

Then modified the `package.json` test command to `./bin/test-runner.bash`. The only ugly thing is the arbitrary sleep command, but it works consistently for now.